# AngularJs UIRouting

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am trying to use UI router but I can't get to open the view of the first page don't know why it won't show the template. It would only show the index.html element. Help would be appreciated I am new to Angular

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Webstie Designing</title>
<!-- Angular Scripts -->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src ="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- Application Scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript">"app/app.js"</script>
</head>
<body id="page-top" ng-app="portfolio">

<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#/">Web Designing</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>




 (function(){
            "use strict";
            var app = angular.module("portfolio",["ui.router"]);
            app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider",
                function("$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider"){
                    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
                        $stateProvider
                            .state("home",{
                                    url:"/",
                                    templateUrl:"app/Intro.html"
                            })
                    }]
            );
 }());
```

Comment: Do you receive any exception?

Comment: I don't use an IDE so don't know :(

Comment: Are your files located in the right places? Intro.html is indeed under app folder?

Comment: I have even tried using a HTML code inside it like <h1>Hi</h1> But no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to refer `app.js` script reference correctly to make `portfolio` module available for `ng-app`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">"app/app.js"</script>
```

Comment: Don't use a Console. Can you check that out please? I said the magical word :D

Comment: @NoumanSaif press `F12` key of your keyboard and it will show up various of various tab on your browser bottom...select console tag from it(most probably by default its open), then checkout log there

Comment: Don't use Google chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104749/discussion-between-nouman-saif-and-pankaj-parkar).